# disabling a button if the product already exist

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

This is the JavaScript Function that Jump to the relevant page

```
    function bun(){
    //var quantity=parseInt(fid);   

        window.location = 'ubun.php'    

    }

    function pat(){
    //var quantity=parseInt(fid);   

        window.location = 'upatties.php'    

    }
    function pats(){
    //var quantity=parseInt(fid);   

        window.location = 'utoppings.php'   

    }
    function sau(){
    //var quantity=parseInt(fid);   

        window.location = 'usauces.php' 

    }

</script>
```

This is the if else function code that are problematic

```
<input type="button" value="Bun Selection" 
      <?php 
      if($fid==4 || $fid==8 || $fid==11 ||$fid==21 ||$fid==5 ||$fid==6||$fid==7||$fid==9||$fid==10||$fid==41||$fid==40||$fid==12||$fid==13||$fid==14
                ||$fid==15||$fid==16||$fid==17||$fid==18||$fid==19||$fid==20||$fid==22
                ||$fid==23||$fid==24||$fid==25||$fid==26||$fid==27||$fid==28||$fid==29
                ||$fid==30) 
      {
         echo ' disabled=disabled ';
      }
      else
      {
            echo ' onclick=bun() ';
      }

    ?>
     />

     <input type="button" value="Patties Selection" 
      <?php 


      if($fid==8 || $fid==11 ||$fid==21 
                ||$fid==9||$fid==10||$fid==41||$fid==40||$fid==12||$fid==13||$fid==14
                ||$fid==15||$fid==16||$fid==17||$fid==18||$fid==19||$fid==20||$fid==22
                ||$fid==23||$fid==24||$fid==25||$fid==26||$fid==27||$fid==28||$fid==29
                ||$fid==30) 
      {
         echo ' disabled=disabled ';
      }
      else
      {
          echo ' onclick=pat() '; 
      }

    ?>
    />

     <input type="button" value="Toppings Selection" 
      <?php if($fid==11 ||$fid==21
                ||$fid==40||$fid==12||$fid==13||$fid==14
                ||$fid==15||$fid==16||$fid==17||$fid==18||$fid==19||$fid==20||$fid==22
                ||$fid==23||$fid==24||$fid==25||$fid==26||$fid==27||$fid==28||$fid==29
                ||$fid==30) 
      {
         echo ' disabled=disabled ';
      }
      else
      {
          echo 'onclick=pats()'; 
      }
    ?>
    />


     <input type="button" value="Sauces Selection" 
      <?php if($fid==21 || $fid==22
                ||$fid==23||$fid==24||$fid==25||$fid==26||$fid==27||$fid==28||$fid==29
                ||$fid==30||$fid==40) 
      {
         echo ' disabled=disabled ';
      }
      else
      {
          echo ' onclick=sau() '; 
      }
    ?>
/>
```

The above code run smoothly when i first go to the shopping cart bun, then patties then toppings and finally sauces. the button will disable one at a time for example if i pick bun then the bun selection will be disable, it is the same with patties, toppings and sauces, the button will disable after the selected product are chosen inorder.

If it is in random then my main problem is that when i pick sauce first then the other three button (bun, patties and toppings)  will also disappear. It is the same with if i choose toppings first the other two button (bun and patties) will disappear, but the sauce button can be click.

I was trying to pick the product at random choices.Are there any solution to my problem?

fid is the id for product id......
for bun id (4,5,6,7)
for patties id (8,9,10,41)
for toppings id (11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20)
for sauces id (20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,40)

Comment: Why does each button have duplicate ids? ie pid 22. And not just have there own?

Comment: I believe there is a problem with IDs of products. As @BG101 said, try to make them unique globally instead of unique only in a concrete category.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use in_array function in php.
it make your code easier to read and clean

```
<?php
        $fid =7; // this is only to show
        $ids = array(1,2,3,4,5,6,8,); // this is the array item to be compare

        if (in_array($fid, $ids)) // check if $fid is in list ($ids)
        {
            echo ' disabled=disabled '; // this will output if $fid is in the array list
        }else{
            echo ' onclick=bun() '; // this will output if $fid is not in the array list
        }
?>
```

this will ouput "onclick=bun()" because 7 is not in the list. Hope this will help.